# How to start and continue studying world's politics

Tags: political-theory, political-system, history, international

Over last years I started to develop strong interest in politics and the way world works.

I'm 23 year-old student of engineering, so I don't really get in touch with these topics in University. I had some history classes in high school, but didn't get whole picture there. Recently I started to study history on my own, just to get an idea on how are the nations connected and how they got formed.

I'd say I have good knowledge of political situation in my country (central Europe), but when I try to argument some things I use to stumble upon the problem of not knowing theoretic principles behind (eg some basic properties of democratic system, ...).

So what I'd like to do is systematically study history, political science and also some recent views on world's political situation development. I know that the kind of knowledge can't be gained over short period and that it's a life long process, but I want to work on it. I want to have my own strong opinion, but based on knowledge and facts.

Can you recommend some lists of books, online courses or some structure that I can start with?

Comment: Hi and welcome to politics.stackexchange. I'm not sure that a question asking for book recommendations or online courses are a really good fit here. First of all, the number of possible answers is just very high. There is literally tons of published material of politics. Maybe you want to narrow the subject down a bit. Secondly, the answers will be very much opinionated. Some may just prefer author X over Y but question that are like polls typically do not work well. Finally, such recommendations may get outdated soon. Let's see.

Comment: I'm also a bit unsure if this question coud be constrained as within the scope of the site. But in any case I would say that participating in this community would be a good start. Why not ask about those theoretical principles for starters? As an extra, books aside, I would recommend you to subscribe to some good news/philosophy/history newsletters/youtube channels/etc. It's quick and free information and with about 20 min per day you'll be up to date to most of the major issues.